# Pandas column not converting to string

Tags: pandas, type-conversion

I have a large dataset in python/pandas, and it's behaving very strangely. I have a column, `df['station']`, with numeric and string values, and I have converted it into an object. If I do dtypes, the column claims to be of dtype object.

station                           object

However, when I run `df['station'].value_counts()` on the column, it says the dtype is int64

[image: Pandas series showing as int even though I have strings]

I'm unable to access the values that are strings, if I try  `df[df['station']=='NONE']` or  `df[df['station']=='S52']` which are both shown to be present in the value_counts() attached image, nothing shows up.

I tried to remove NaNs from the column, and then converting to string and running value_counts() again, but it still shows up as int64.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the `int64` is the dtype of the new series from the `value_counts()` method, the index of the series are the strings from your `station` column. I suspect your strings may have white spaces, try `df[df['station'].str.strip()=='S52']`

Comment: @Manakin thank you so much, this helped!